# Trying to understand GOD rb

Tags: ruby, god, process-monitoring

I'm facing few confusion with GOD documentation

Firstly my configuration script look like this

```
DIRECTORY = "/Users/joshianiket22/myProject/god_script"
God.pid_file_directory = DIRECTORY
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "mess"
  w.start = "ruby /Users/joshianiket22/myProject/god_script/simple.rb"
  w.pid_file =  File.join(DIRECTORY,'simple.pid')
  puts File.join(DIRECTORY,'simple.pid')
  w.stop = "ruby -e 'puts \"#{DateTime.now}\"'"
  w.log = File.join(DIRECTORY,'god.log')
  w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)
  w.interval = 10.seconds
   w.start_if do |start| 
    start.condition(:process_running) do |c| 
      puts "Inside start condition"
      c.interval = 5.seconds 
      c.running = false
    end 
  end 
end
```

**Confusion 1** : GOD PID FILE DILEMMA

In GOD documentation it mention

[image]

Now I have clear I have set the **pid_file** and **pid_file_directory** yet the PID is no where to be seen in that directory that is define in my configuration

FYI, started GOD with `sudo` so assuming directory would be writable by GOD

**Confusion 2:** START_IF CONDITION

[image]

Now That how one define a start_if condition now I not able to understand the use case for this.
Also word condition what conditions to set of conditions

- Is :process_running a set of condition?, if yes what are other set of 
  condition for **start_if**
- Also what does the attributes inside the **do block** suppose to do? and when would they be executed?

  More precisely I referring to 
  c.running = false ( what it does internal and what other list of attributes are available on  **start_if**)

**Confusion  3** (start/stop/restart command)

Now given my configuration file which has a **start** command written in it, now  is it also required to write a stop and restart command as well in configuration

so that when run the following

> sudo god stop mess
>   sudo god restart mess

they would get executed

Assuming I don't write them

- what would happen if run them ?
- Will GOD will eventually Kill the running process when stop command i.e `sudo god stop mess' is executed? or restart the running
  process when restart command i.e`sudo god restart mess` is executed"?

Can anyone share light on it

**Confusion 4** (Whether or whether not to daemonize the process):

According to GOD documentation 
[image]

Now Consider I explicitly put by process to background inside GOD something like

```
w.start = "ruby /Users/joshianiket22/myProject/god_script/simple.rb &"
```

what would happen in such case

- Will GOD monitor them for stop and restart command ?

So daemonizing your process inside GOD (in start command ) can be consider a valid approach assuming that GOD know that the process has gone in background
and it react to all command start / stop / restart command on that process when run against GOD ?

like

> sudo god stop mess
>   sudo god restart mess

Can anyone put some light on this as well

So here are list of question extracted from  above

- Why isn't the pid_file_directory syntax working?
- if :process_running is a set of conditions what other conditions does **start_if** contains also what c.running = false (internally do)
- Is it necessary to write/define `stop` and `restart` in God configuration
- If the process is explicity move to background will GOD still monitor it for command like `stop|restart` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially answer some part of my question

**Question:** Is it necessary to write/define stop and restart in God configuration

**Answer**  Well not really you can define your own command but if in case you dont define there is default `lambda` for `stop` and `restart`

Straight from GOD documentation

[image]

**Question:** If the process is explicity move to background will GOD still monitor it for command like stop|restart etc

**Answer**: Answer is **YES** and **NO** , No because if you dont give GOD the `pid` file to monitor it will not monitor the process running in background

Again from GOD documentation

[image]

**Question:** If :process_running is a set of conditions what other conditions does `start_if` contains also what c.running = false (internally do)

**Answer**: Well I will answer this question in 2 parts

- What other conditions does `start_if` contains ?

  `Ans:` Well the best place to look that is  under conditions directory of god check over [here](https://github.com/mojombo/god/tree/master/lib/god/conditions)
    there is `process_running` condition also exists
- What **c.running = false** (internally do)?

  `Ans:` Well c.running is internally used to check (the check is perform with respect to process id and running variable) whether a process was running prior when `god` start so if the process i.e(c.running = true) is running and the `pid` file pointed has the corrected all work well but if the `c.running = true` and `pid` monitored is different or does not exist it keep looping hence it advisable to use `c.running = true` only if the process was already running and correct `pid_file` (with correct `pid` in it is) is define in god file .
  One can check that over [here](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/master/lib/god/conditions/process_running.rb#L42-L62)

**Note:** Accepting my answer since only one question is left and I believe it was mostly not working because of my wrong doing (i.e the pid wasn't getting stored in desired directory) :) 
  Rest all question are answered by me.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for sharing this. I guess `pid_file` and `pid_file_directory` setting must be combined so god can see the correct pid? Could you shed some light on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703031/god-wont-restart-died-process?